# Python: How to Use ML for Extracting specific Data from various PDF

Tags: python, opencv, machine-learning, deep-learning, nlp

Need assistance with a ML project I am currently trying to create.

I receive a lot of invoices from a lot of different suppliers - all in their own unique layout. I need to extract 4 key elements from the invoices. These 4 elements are all located in a table/line/sections items for all the different invoices.

Elements are :

1. Bill No / Invoice No
2. Date of Billing
3. SGST, CGST applied
4. Total Amount/ Total Amount Due/ Total Bill Due

Input File:
[Please find the input file link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Kmg5QYQrnnhZ05wsGA0jBkCC1FJOUfbd/view)

I started this project with a template approach, based on regular expressions. This, however, was not scalable at all and I ended up with tons of different rules.

What I have applied so far:

```
import textract
text = textract.process('datafile.pdf')

processed_text=text.lower()
processed_text= processed_text.replace('\n',' ')
processed_text= processed_text.replace('*',' ')
processed_text= processed_text.replace('/',' ')

from nltk.corpus import stopwords
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize
text_tokens = word_tokenize(processed_text)
text_without_stopwords = [word for word in text_tokens if not word in stopwords.words{}]
processed_text = " ".join(text_without_stopwords)

regex_invoice_no = re.compile(r"Invoice No\s*:\s*(\d+)")
regex_date = re.compile(r"Date of Billing\s*:\s*(\d\d\.\d\d\.\d{4})")
regex_SGST = re.compile(r"SGST:\s*:\s*(\d+)")
regex_CGST = re.compile(r"CGST:\s*:\s*(\d+)")
regex_total_due = re.compile(r"Total Amount Due:\s*:\s*(\d+)")

invoice_no= re.search(regex_invoice_no, output_string.getvalue()).group(1),
issue_date= re.search(regex_date, output_string.getvalue()).group(1),
sgst= re.search(regex_SGST, output_string.getvalue()).group(1),
cgst= re.search(regex_CGST, output_string.getvalue()).group(1),
amount= re.search(regex_total_due, output_string.getvalue()).group(1)}

print(invoice_no, issue_date, sgst,cgst, amount)
```

**Output:**

For each invoice like the one above, I need the output for each PDF. This could for example be something like this:

```
{
"Invoice No":"INXXXXXXXX",
"SGST":"260",
"CGST":"290",
"Date of Billing":"3-",
"Total Amount Due":"258.93"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be something like this.

```
import PyPDF2
import re
mypdf = open('C:\\your_path\\your_file.pdf', mode='rb')
pdf_document = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(mypdf)
pdf_document.numPages
first_page = pdf_document.getPage(0)
print(first_page.extractText())

pdf_document = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(mypdf)
pdf_document.numPages

page_one = pdf_document.getPage(0)
first = re.findall(r'Invoice No', str(first_page.extractText()))
second = re.findall(r'SGST', str(first_page.extractText()))
third = re.findall(r'CGST', str(first_page.extractText()))
print(first,second,third)

first=str('Invoice Number:')+str(first)
second=str('SGST:')+str(second)
third=str('CGST:') + str(third)
final = first + second + third

print(final)
```

Of course, you can loop through a bunch of PDF files and append all of these data points to a list, that grows and grows.

In terms of the ML stuff, I can't tell what you are doing, but you can find some good ideas of how to get started from the link below.

https://github.com/ASH-WICUS/Notebooks/blob/master/Natural%20Language%20Processing%20-%20Amazon%20Reviews.ipynb